# Condition for cyclic module

Tags: modules, direct-sum

Let A, B be cyclic R-modules. Is there any condition of R to ensure that $M=A\oplus B$ is a cyclic R-module?

Comment: What is $R$ initially assumed to be? A commutative, unital ring?

Comment: For commutative rings, see the astract version of the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Generalization_to_arbitrary_rings).

Comment: @Arthur R is a unital ring.

Answer (score 0):

For commutative rings, this is impossible. In other words, if $R$ is any commutative ring, there exist two cyclic $R$-modules $A,B$ such that $A \oplus B$ is not cyclic.

*proof:*

Let $M$ be any maximal ideal of $R$. Then $R/M=k$ is a field, and it is a cyclic $R$-module. Let
$$A=B=k$$
Suppose that $A \oplus B$ is cyclic as an $R$-module. Then, it has a generator, say $x$.

Then $x$ generates $A \oplus B$ also as a $k$-module. This means that
$$\dim_k (A \oplus B)=1$$
But this is a contradiction, since $$A \oplus B = k \oplus k = k^2$$
which has dimension $2$.

Comment: Well, there is the possibility (depending on the definitions) that $R$ is the zero ring.